# Why does httpWebRequest.GetResponse() timeout when stream is not used?

Tags: c#, timeout, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I just ran into a very strange behavior that I would like to understand. I am reading an image via HttpWebRequest. The following code raises a timeout exception:

```
HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
httpWebRequest.Timeout = 5000;
HttpWebResponse httpWebReponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
Stream stream = httpWebReponse.GetResponseStream();
```

Please note that stream is not used anywhere else afterwards. However, if I add the following line:

```
Image image = Image.FromStream(stream);
```

Also here note that image is not used anywhere later on. Can anyone explain why I get the timeout in the first case?

Comment: Until you actually read the stream, the response object is kept open. If you don't read it within 5 seconds, the response can't complete and it times out. Getting the stream doesn't read it in, it just gets a reference to the stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. This behavior leads to very strange results if you comment a processing function in a completely different section for debugging purposes.

Comment: The alternative is to read it into a buffer (`MemoryStream` or some other place) and return the response right away. The idea with web requests is to get the data quickly and release the connection. Process later if its a long running or low priority issue.